# Google Appengine: app.yaml basic_scaling strange behavior

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a very basic app.yaml file. When I deploy the file with this in it:

```
basic_scaling:
  #max_instances: 11
  #idle_timeout: 10m
#instance_class: B1
```

everything works. If I un-comment out instance_class: B1 I get the error "class B1 only available for basic_scaling" which it already is so why the error. The other thing is if I leave everything the way it is but un-comment out the max_instances then everything uploads but when I go to the project I get a 500 error. Changing the scaling to automatic and leaving the max_instances uncommented out does not cause errors.

strange behavior!

Answer (score 1):

It works with this format below:

```
instance_class: B1

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

or

```
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m

instance_class: B1
```

You misconfigured the app.yaml, the `instance_class` is not under the `basic_scaling` attribute.

#### UPDATE:

If you deploy the app.yaml with comment on the element of `instance_class: B1`:

```
#instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

it will result to default which is `instance_class: B2`. Then if you also add comment on the `max_instances: 11` and `idle_timeout: 10m`:

```
#instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  #max_instances: 11
  #idle_timeout: 10m
```

it will deploy your app engine into `instance_class: F1` and `automatic_scaling`.

If you include an actual screenshot of the error in your answer, it can help us to determine the issue.

Comment: Let me know if this answer fixed your problem.

Comment: actually the instance_class: is back on the same line as basic_scaling, I accidentally formatted that snippet wrong here.

Comment: Regarding to the 500 error, there are so many possibilities you can also include your logs in your question if there's an error. Maybe after your deployment the instance could not start immediately and successfully.